# V4l2 MJPEG Chroma Subsumpling

Tags: c++, mjpeg, v4l2

My cam gives me jpeg with chroma sub-sampling `4:2:2`, but I need `4:2:0`.

- Can I change MJPEG default chroma sub-sampling with *v4l2*?

Comment: Question is rather clear if you know what [v4l2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux#Version_2) is, and what [the asked chroma sub-sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling#4:2:0) is. Downvotes, or at least close votes are unwarranted in my opinion.

Comment: Possible source for answer/solution: http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/V4L2-PIX-FMT-M420.html

Comment: @Grotrek It's generally a good idea to add a piece of code to a question like this. Otherwise there will be people who don't understand the question and downvote/vote to close (and I don't  really blame them).

Comment: my cam support only 2 formats: MJPEG and YUYV(YUV422). MJpeg gives my packed image with chroma sub-sampling 4:2:2 and YUV422 gives unpacked image with chroma sub-sampling 4:2:2 too. I need to convert one of them to packed jpeg image with chroma 4:2:0.  Convertion from raw 422 image to 420 image and then packing it is very slow, so I wan't to change MJPEG chroma sub-sampling to 4:2:0

Comment: You **have to** do : MJPEGIN -> 422 -> 420 > MJPEGOUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v4l2` itself provides a very thin layer around the actual video data that is transferred: it will simply give you the formats that the camera (the *hardware*!!) delivers.

so if your hardware offers two distinct formats, then there is **no way** that `v4l2` will offer you anything else.

you might want to checkout out `libv4l2` library that does *some* basic colorspace conversion: in general it will have conversion from most exotic hardware formats to a handful of "standard" formats, so your application does not need to support *all* formats any hardware manufacturer can come up with. however, it is not very likely that these standard formats include a very specific (compressed) format, like the one you need.